# Unable to call Python method from Robot Framework: No keyword with the name 'method_name' was found

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, keyword, pythonpath

I'm facing an issue when trying to call a Python method from a Robot Framework test case. I have the following Python method defined in a file named campaign.py:

`def print_something_test(self, text): print(text)`

In my Robot Framework test, I'm attempting to call this method as follows:

```
*** Test Cases ***
GIVEN Print Something Test Colombo

*** Keywords ***
Print Something Test ${text}
    print_something_test ${text}
```

However, when I run this test, I receive the following error:

`No keyword with the name 'print_something_test' was found.`

I've ensured that the campaign.py file is accessible and should be correctly imported. Is there something I'm missing in the way I'm calling this Python method from Robot Framework? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

P.s. I called the "print_something_test" method inside the main method to test. It's working fine.

Comment: Looks like `print_something_test()` is a class method, not a standalone function.

Comment: `def print_something_test(text):
    logger.console(text)` I tried this too. Same error. Also, my team members can successfully run the code.

Comment: **1.** There are not enough info to investigate the problem. Please, provide the name of your python file, name of the class that contains the method, and header of the robot file where you import the python file.  There are could be something with import, or name of the class doesn't match name of python file. [link](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-name)

Comment: **2. ** Also please notice the next potential problem. As RobotFramework ignores the underlines and spaces in the keyword names, then RF could consider the same name `Print Something Test` and `print_something_test`. So, better to slightly rename either python method or your robot keyword. So the last one will not hide the first one

Comment: You seem to be trying to have two keywords with the same name. At least part of the solution will involve renaming either the keyword or the python function.